# How to turn off Desktop environment but stay with ability to use GUI programs?

Tags: command-line, 19.04, desktop-environments

I'm a beginner in Linux system, so my question might be a nonsense which I'm sorry for. But I've been wondering if there a way to turn off all graphical options regarding desktop environment so I could manipulate file system only through terminal but I could use GUI programs like a browser or text editor at the same time. Thank you.

Comment: What text editor/browser do you mean.  If you mean `lynx` `w3m` and `vim` `nano` etc that are text browsers & editors - as they don't need a gui desktop they'll still run. GUI browsers however will call the desktop in memory to write/display anything from the screen, it won't be there so won't be able to interact with you & won't run (error messages).

Comment: A boat must have the correct design and components to float. Try this in a VM: You can easily uninstall your GUI file manager...but doing so may break your system in ways that you do not expect.

Comment: Which parts of a file-system a user can manipulate depends on the users privileges, not on the used tool. Normally the user is restricted to his home-directory which he can manipulate. To be able to manipulate system-files or files owned by another user you'd have to evaluate the privileges of the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. However you can simply switch to a minimalist window manager (such as i3wm, sway, etc…) session instead and use a terminal app as your primary interface.

Otherwise, if you want to go for a full terminal interface only, and use only terminal based browsers and such, you could install the *Ubuntu Server* edition instead, and go from there.